# How to implement cookie based route guard using CanActivateFn?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a router guard:

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginAuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  return true;
};
```

and service with verifyToken function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
  url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login';
  token: string = '';

  async login(formObject: any) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${this.url}`, formObject, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      console.log('http cookie set!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async verifyToken() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${this.url}`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

If i want to enter a resource, the request is send to the endpoint using validateCookie. If it is true, i can access it, if not, i cant. How to implement it using `CanActivateFn`?

edit:
i tried:

```
export const loginAuthGuard: CanActivateFn = async (route, state) => {
  try {
    const isValid = await AuthService.verifyToken();
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

but i got:
`Property 'verifyToken' does not exist on type 'typeof AuthService'.` for no reason

Comment: You need to inject auth service. You can do let authService = inject(AuthService); then you can use it to call verify method